# Почему shared_ptr не конфликтует с HANDLE из WinAPI? С++

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-ptr

Я решил сделать обертку для `HANDLE` из WinAPI, который представляет из себя `void*`. Нужная мне обертка использовалась бы с функцией `OpenProcess()`, которая возвращает `HANDLE` открытого процесса. Обертка выглядит так:

```
using Handle = std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<HANDLE>>;

typedef struct SharedHandle : Handle {

    using Handle::shared_ptr;

    SharedHandle(HANDLE ptr) 
        : Handle::shared_ptr(ptr, CloseHandle) {}

} SHandle;
```

То есть по сути это `shared_ptr<void>`, только с делитером, который представляет из себя `WinAPI` функцию `CloseHandle`. И тут я подумал, что если создать два таких указателя к одному процессу, то у нас создадутся два `shared_ptr`, которые указывают на одно и то же место, но друг о друге ничего не знают. Согласно документации это ведет к UB:

```
// После выхода из области видимости они попытаются вызвать делитер CloseHandle
// Дважды на одном указателе, что ведет к UB
SharedHandle handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, process_id) // 1
SharedHandle handle2 = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, process_id) // 2
```

Однако этого не произошло! Я начал копать и вывел значение указателя, которое возвращает `OpenProcess`. Мне вывело два совершенно разных адреса! Хотя id процесса был один и тот же. Почему `OpenProcess` возвращает различные `handl'ы` для одного процесса и насколько вероятен исход, что рано или поздно вернет два одинаковых указатели и `shared_ptr` вызовет ошибку?

Comment: OpenProcess возвращает дескриптор, а не адрес. Это только тип указатель на void. Ну и непонятно, на кой ляд тут понадобился `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @user7860670 да, запутался в определениях. Но даже если дескриптор, разве он не должен однозначно опеределять процесс? Почему он разный при каждом вызове и может ли он когда-нибудь совпасть и снести мне кабину при использовании `shared_ptr`? Сам умный указатель мне по сути нужен, чтобы контролировать возможность закрыть открытый процесс когда это нужно. Несколько функций, например, используют один процесс и, когда уже все указатели не используются и вышли из области видимости, соединение закрывается при помощи `CloseHandle()`

Comment: @user7860670 можно сказать, что я в целях обучения пытаюсь построить себе удобный ООП интерфейс для работы с процессами из WinAPI. Чтобы все делалось легко, просто и понятно

Comment: Он однозначно определяет процесс. Дескрипторы разные при каждом вызове, потому что это дескрипторы, а не просто указатели. Возвращаемые дескрипторы гарантировано не должны совпадать с уже открытыми дескрипторами (и с уже закрытыми тоже, но не гарантированно).

Comment: Использование shared_ptr лишает возможности контролировать закрытие процесса, так как владение разделяется.

Comment: @user7860670 ну конкретно в данном случае меня это устраивает, поскольку мне нужно, чтобы процесс закрывался только после полного окончания использования. То есть когда все функции, использующие дескриптор  прекратили работу и дескриптор вышел из области видимости. Возможно потом это нужно будет переделать, но пока что меня это устраивает. Не попробую - не узнаю, благо это проект не реальный, а для обучения, так что можно и поэкспериментировать